# sed search and replace \" but not \\"

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace all escaped characters \" in a string with "" but not if \" is preceded by a \

So that input such as:

- \"\"\"\" would return """"""""
- \"\\"\"\" would return ""\\"""""
- \" would return ""
- \"\" would return """"
- \\"\" would return \\"""
- \"\\" would return ""\\"
- \\\\\\\" would return \\\\\\\"

So far I have

```
$ echo sed -e 's/\([^\]\)\\"/\1""/;s/^\\"/""/'
```

but in the case of

```
$ echo '\"\"\"\"\"' | sed -e 's/\([^\]\)\\"/\1""/;s/^\\"/""/'`
```

I am getting incorrect results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of sed are you using?  Is it POSIX or does it have extensions (like GNU sed)?

Comment: POSIX compatible would be best.

Comment: I'm confused by the ansamples.  you say `\"\\"\"\" would return ""\\"""""` and `\\"\" would return \\"""` so the escaped backslash would stay escaped.  But then you say `\"\\" would return ""\"` so the escaped backslash wouldn't stay escaped.  And the last example has seven backslashes so the double quote is escaped with a backslash but in the result it isn't converted - or did you mean for there to be an even number of backslashes?

Comment: Sorry I should have used single quotes around the examples when writing it because the \ are interpreted as escapes and were removed, I tried to escape the escapes but I must have missed one. Same goes for the last example. 

In the last case I am only looking for any \" that isn't preceded by a \ so any number of \\\\ before " would be ignored regardless of number (Odd or even).

Comment: You may find it helpful (while debugging) to specify both the input an the sed program in files.  Then you won't have to deal with escaping for the shell until you have to.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\\\\"/\n/g;s/\\"/""/g;s/\n/\\\\"/g' file
```

Replace all occurances of the string you want untouched by something else (`\n` is a good choice), replace the string you want changed globally, reinstate the first set of strings.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function myreplace {
    echo "$1" | sed -e "s/[\\]\"/MYDUMMY/g" \
                    -e 's/\\MYDUMMY/\\\\"/g' \
                    -e 's/MYDUMMY/""/g'
}

myreplace '\"\"\"\"'
myreplace '\"\\"\"\"'
myreplace '\"'
myreplace '\"\"' 
myreplace '\\"\"' 
myreplace '\"\\"' 
myreplace '\\\\\\\"'
```

Executing the script above results in:

```
""""""""
""\\"""""
""
""""
\\"""
""\\"
\\\\\\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a sed loop will allow not having to pick a unique replacement string for an unknown dataset.

```
sed -e 's/^\\"/""/;:inner; s/\([^\]\)[\]"/\1""/g; t inner'


$ echo '\"\"\"\"' | sed -e 's/^\\"/""/;:inner; s/\([^\]\)[\]"/\1""/g;t inner'
""""""""
$ echo '\"\\"\"\"' | sed -e 's/^\\"/""/;:inner; s/\([^\]\)[\]"/\1""/g; t inner'
""\\"""""
$ echo '\"' | sed -e 's/^\\"/""/;:inner; s/\([^\]\)[\]"/\1""/g; t inner'
""
$ echo '\"\"' | sed -e 's/^\\"/""/;:inner; s/\([^\]\)[\]"/\1""/g; t inner'
""""
$ echo '\\"\"' | sed -e 's/^\\"/""/;:inner; s/\([^\]\)[\]"/\1""/g; t inner'
\\"""
$ echo '\"\\"' | sed -e 's/^\\"/""/;:inner; s/\([^\]\)[\]"/\1""/g; t inner'
""\\"
$ echo '\\\\\\\"' | sed -e 's/^\\"/""/;:inner; s/\([^\]\)[\]"/\1""/g; t inner'
\\\\\\\"
```